# How to get the code in my IDE to reflect an accepted pull request from someone else

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I'm been writing and pushing code to GitHub by myself for a while now, but recently another developer made a PR and I accepted it. Now, because my file in VSCode doesn't reflect the small changes that he made, I'm a bit worried to push new changes that I've made. Will it overwrite his changes?

I understand that this is a really basic question, but to be honest it has been a bit difficult to search for. I guess I don't really have the language to ask the question in a shorter, 'google-search' way.

If anyone can help, thank you!

Comment: I think this is what branching is used for, so instead of always using the main branch when you want to change something you make a new branch and then when you are finished merge it into the main. Then you can handle the overwriting issues when you try to merge.

Comment: Alternatively maybe you could stash your changes, pull in the main branch which would have all the most recent changes and then manually add your changes into that and then commit.

Comment: Tell us what repository this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Will pushing a new local change overwrite his changes?**

No*

**How do I get the changes from the merged PR into my IDE?**

[git pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

**Explanation**

It's implied in the question that until now your workflow has been something like:

- make a change
- commit change locally ([`git add foo.file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) + [`git commit -m "adding foo file"`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit))

Periodically thereafter:

- pushing those changes from local to GitHub ([`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push))

With a single contributor (you) the local copies of files have always been in sync with remote files (or ahead of them, after committing and before pushing).

Let's take a look at what happens with a new local change and you want to push it to the remote, to see if it will clobber the pull request's changes:

```
$ git push
To github.com:username/repo.git
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:username/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Git aborted, doing nothing at all. The help text includes the action to take:

> Integrate the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again

[`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) will update your local branch, and also update files on disk to match, integrating changes made on the remote. This is the step which will 'get the code into my IDE'

Therefore all that's required is:

```
$ git pull
$ git push
```

If there are merge conflicts found when pulling from the remote take care to resolve them to integrate the changes on the remote and locally, made to the same files in parallel.

`*` - *unless you force push, don't do that :)*

Comment: This was very well written, and solved my problem! Thank you :)